# Redis connection settings for app "surviving" redis connectivity issues

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I'm using azure redis cache for certain performance monitoring services. Basically when events like page loads, etc occur, I send a fire and forget command to redis to record the event. My goal is for my app to function fine *whether or not it can contact the redis server*. I'm looking for a best practice for this scenario. I would be OK with losing some events if necessary. I've been finding that even though I'm using fire and forget, the app staggers when the web server runs into high latency or connectivity issues with the server.

I'm using StackExchange.Redis. Any best practice configuration options/programming practices for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I was implementing a singleton pattern on the connection turned out to be blocking requests. Once I fixed this my app behaves as I want (e.g. it still functions when redis connection dies).